# .htaccess direct domain to subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect www.example.com to /example/ on my webserver, but it appears to only be redirecting the index.php page. An additional issue is the main file displays as http://tunedu.com/tunedu/ when I would like it to display as tunedu.com

**Live example:**
This page works: http://tunedu.com/tunedu/
This page doesn't work: http://tunedu.com/school.php?id=75

Any regex changes I do try end up just breaking everything. The .htacess code is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /tunedu/ [L]
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm really confused about what you are trying to accomplish. First you say you want to redirect, then you say you want to rewrite. Could you maybe add some more details? In the case that doesn't work, what doesn't work about it? What is happening instead? What would you desire to happen?

Comment: Right sorry, I'm really new to htaccess. So I am trying to run multiple domain names on a single web server. In order to have them showing different content, I want them to load files from subdirectories of the web server. In the case that doesn't work, no content appears, it just plain doesn't work, no content loads, but for the case that does work, it loads a page. I have tested all the files on a local server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do such a thing is by setting VirtualHosts on your webserver (either Apache, nginx or another...). Using htaccess for this seems quite painful.

Assuming you're using Apache, here's a useful link: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are not using VirtualHost to set that up.

But in case you want to go the mod_rewrite way here is an useful link:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/vhosts.html

I hope that helps.